# What differentiates swipe gestures in iOS mail preview’s body?

Tags: ios, mail.app, ipados, gesture

This one has me stumped and has for some time. On iPad when previewing a Mail message, you can swipe on the actual body of the mail message preview itself. If you swipe from left to right, one of two things happens:

1. The message list is displayed
2. The “toggle mark as read” indicator shows up (the same as swiping on a message in the list.)

The thing is, for the life of me I can’t figure out what differentiates between the two. I have tried short pressing, long pressing, light pressing, hard pressing, tap-and-delay, slow swipes, fast swipes, swiping from the left side of the screen, swiping from the right side of the screen, swiping in the middle of the screen.  Every combination that I can think of and it just seems to be random which of the two gestures gets triggered, Most of the time showing the list.

Swiping from right to left however works one-hundred percent of the time to show the message options.

So… Anybody have any idea what’s causing this? How do you distinguish between the two?